# Calling Laravel relationship with aggregate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

If I have a Laravel 5.5 model called `User` that `hasMany` `Post`s and each `Post` `hasMany` `Hit`s, is there an aggregate function I can call to get the total number of `Hit`s for a `User` across all `Post`s, where the `Hit` was created in the last week?

It seems like there may be a clever way to do it besides doing something like

```
$hits = $user->posts()->hits()
```

and then looping over those hits to check created date.

In this case it seems like raw sql would be better, but I figured there may be an Eloquent way to handle a situation like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the right solution is just to use a [`HasManyThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship to grab all the `Hit` rows, joined through the `posts` table.

So it'd look like this on the `User` model (roughly):

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(
    Hit::class,
    Post::class
    // if you have non-standard key names you can specify them here-- see docs
);
```

Then when you have your `User` model you can just call `$user->hits` to get a collection of all the associated hits through all the user's `Post`s

Answer (score 0):

You can add the code below to your `Post` model.

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('hitCount', function ($builder) {
        $builder->withCount('hits');
    });
}
```

It automatically provides a field `hits_count` whenever you fetch a post.

```
$post = Post::first();
$hits = $post->hits_count; //Count hits that belongs to this post
```

You can read the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) to customize it to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Set `HasManyThrough` relation in the `User` model:

```
public function hits()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Hits','App\Models\Posts','user_id','post_id','id');
}
```

then you can do this:

```
$reults = $user->hits()->where('hits_table_name.created_at', '>=', Carbon::today()->subWeek())->count();
```

[HasManyThrough Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Use `DB::enableQueryLog();` and `DB::getQueryLog();` to see if executed SQL Query is correct;